# VSCode import path intellisense for custom files extensions

Tags: javascript, ide, intellisense, visual-studio-code

When writing a code that will be later pushed through webpack, it is possible to use custom loaders for non-standard files. In effect it is possible to write

```
import image from './assets/image.png';
```

and it will be properly handled. The problem is VSCode doesn't provide autocompletion for files like `.png`, `.svg`, `.scss` and so on.

Is it possible to do so by some settings or an extension?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to fix it using [Path Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) extension. By default it does not include file extensions and suggests the .js files in addition to the default suggestions by VS Code. It can be changed by adding the following lines to the User Settings:

```
"path-autocomplete.extensionOnImport": true,
"path-autocomplete.excludedItems": {
    "**/*.js": {"when": "**"}
}
```

Comment: Why are excluding js files using ` "**/*.js": {"when": "**"}` ?

Comment: Because they are already suggested by VS code itself, so all js files would appear twice in the suggestions

Comment: @KirillZinovjev any suggestion on excluding folders so that they won't show up twice in suggestion?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Here: 
`"path-autocomplete.excludedItems": {
    "**": { "when": "**", "isDir": true }
}`
Actually, I found this in the extension docs.